# Skipping outputs with anonymous function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

Say I want to create an anonymous function from a m-file-function that returns two outputs. Is it possible to set up the anonymous function such that it only returns the second output from the m-file-function?

Example: `ttest2` returns two outputs, t/f and a probability. If I want to use the t-test with `cellfun`, I might only be interested in collecting the probabilities, i.e. I'd like to write something like this

```
probabilities = cellfun(@(u,v)ttest2(u,v)%take only second output%,cellArray1,cellArray2)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no way I know of *within the expression* of the [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f4-70115.html) to have it select which output to return from a function with multiple possible output arguments. However, you *can* return multiple outputs when you *evaluate* the anonymous function. Here's an example using the function [MAX](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/max.html):

```
>> data = [1 3 2 5 4];  %# Sample data
>> fcn = @(x) max(x);   %# An anonymous function with multiple possible outputs
>> [maxValue,maxIndex] = fcn(data)  %# Get two outputs when evaluating fcn

maxValue =

     5         %# The maximum value (output 1 from max)


maxIndex =

     4         %# The index of the maximum value (output 2 from max)
```

Also, the best way to handle the specific example you give above is to actually just use the [function handle](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/function_handle.html) `@ttest2` as the input to [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html), then get the multiple outputs from [CELLFUN](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/cellfun.html) itself:

```
[junk,probabilities] = cellfun(@ttest2,cellArray1,cellArray2);
```

On newer versions of MATLAB, you can replace the variable `junk` with [`~`](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bresuxt-1.html#br67dkp-1) to ignore the first output argument.

Comment: In other words, I do need to write a wrapper function. Thanks for the clarification! Also: Congrats on 20k!

Comment: @Jonas: Thanks, and congrats on the silver MATLAB badge!

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is to define the function:

```
function varargout = getOutput(func,outputNo,varargin)
    varargout = cell(max(outputNo),1);
    [varargout{:}] = func(varargin{:});
    varargout = varargout(outputNo);
end
```

and then `getOutput(@ttest2,2,u,v)` gives only the `p-value`.

To use it in a `cellfun` you would need to run:

```
probabilities = cellfun(@(u,v)getOutput(@ttest2,2,u,v)...
```

This eliminates the need to write a wrapper every time, but then you have to make sure this function is always in the path.