# Matlab: defining a function handle catching second returned value of a function

Tags: matlab, function-handle

Say that I have a function `foo` defined as

```
   [a b] = foo(c ).
```

If I consider a function handle

```
 f = @(c)foo(c)
```

to be used e.g. in a `cellfun` call, what  I get is an `f` behaving equivalently to a `foo` defined like

```
  a = foo(c)
```

i.e.,  the returned value `b` gets lost.

Therefore, when such an `f` is put in a `cellfun` call, the output cell will have just the `a`s and will miss the `b`s (which I currently care about). *Visually*

```
    cellfun(f,input)

  [a(input{1})]           ?
  [a(input{2})]           ?
     ....            b gets killed along the way
```

---

**Question:** how to define a function handle to `foo` which *catches* just the `b`s? i.e. giving a behavior analogous to a definition of `foo` like

```
  b = foo(c)
```

i.e.^2, *wasting* the  `a`s.

Moreover, is it possible to (efficiently) catch both `a` and `b` in a *unique* `cellfun` call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [documentation of `cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html):

> [A1,...,Am] = cellfun(func,C1,...,Cn) calls the function specified by function handle func and passes elements from cell arrays C1,...,Cn, where n is the number of inputs to function func. **Output arrays A1,...,Am, where m is the number of outputs from function func**, contain the combined outputs from the function calls.

So yes, `cellfun` can use a multi-output function and in this case it simply returns a number of outputs. If you want to use the second one only, you can use `~` to ignore the first one. The same goes for multiple outputs of anonymous functions - they will be returned if you [specify multiple output arguments](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). Here is a simple code:

```
function test
    x{1} = 1;
    x{2} = 2;
    [~, B] = cellfun(@foo, x);
    f=@(c)foo(c);
    [A, B] = f(1);

    function [a b] = foo(x)
        a = x+1;
        b = x+2;
    end
end
```

Comment: Nice, it worked for what concerns the `cellfun` call; in my case I put `[A,B]` and not `[~,B]`, my matlab version doesn't support it. So the second point is successfully answered! As far as I can see the general problem of getting the second returned argument in a lambda definition still holds. Isn't it?

Comment: @Acorbe See the updated answer. It is exactly the same - you can not change the declaration of a function, but you can specify multiple outputs to your anonymous function call.

Comment: Well that I see.. I am still looking for something that doesn't need to do the `[A , B] = foo` stuff. Mainly for retrocompatibility issues. Indeed one can wrap the function `foo` in another function (non function handle), loosing the lambda flavor though. Thank you for highlighting that part of the manual which I read not carefully enough.

Comment: Speaking more abstractly what I need looks more like `f = @(c)foo(x)[2]`

Comment: @Acorbe I understand, but as far as I know, you can not do that. Also, have a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096281/skipping-outputs-with-anonymous-function-in-matlab). The bottom line - you will have to define wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using a cell array as the single output of the function, instead of a function with multiple outputs.

Define your function to return a cell array (or create an auxiliary function that calls the original multiple-output function):

```
function F = foo2(x)
  [a,b,c] = foo(x);
  F = {a, b, c};
end
```

And then you can create a handle that calls your function and gets only one of the cells from the cell array.

```
f = @(x) cell(foo2(x)){2} % This selects the second output
g = @(x) cell(foo2(x)){3} % This selects the third output
```

Which is almost exactly what you were asking for.
You could even create a handle that returns the n-th output

```
f = @(x,n) cell(foo2(x)){n}
```