# How can I make the value of an expression equal to a second return value of another expression

Tags: matlab

Is there an idiomatic way in Matlab to bind the value of an expression to the n<sup>th</sup> return value of another expression?

For example, say I want an array of indices corresponding to the maximum value of a number of vectors stored in a cell array. I can do that by

```matlab
function I = max_index(varargin)
    [~,I]=max(varargin{:});

cellfun(@max_index, my_data);
```

But this requires one to define a function (`max_index`) specific for each case one wants to select a particular return value in an expression. I can of course define a generic function that does what I want:

```matlab
function y = nth_return(n,fun,varargin)
    [vals{1:n}] = fun(varargin{:});
    y = vals{n};
```

And call it like:

```matlab
cellfun(@(x) nth_return(2,@max,x), my_data)
```

Adding such functions, however, makes code snippets less portable and harder to understand. Is there an idiomatic to achieve the same result without having to rely on the custom `nth_return` function?

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Since you already know which return value you want to store, what is the problem with the [~,I] syntax?

Comment: AFAIK, the [~,I] syntax is not usable as part of an expression. I.e. I can not use it in an anonymous function, like in the cellfun() call above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is as far as I know not possible in another way as with the solutions you mention. So just use the syntax:

```
[~,I]=max(var);
```

Or indeed create an extra function. But I would also suggest against this. Just write the extra line of code, in case you want to use the output in another function. I found two earlier questions on stackoverflow, which adress the same topic, and seem to confirm that this is not possible.

[Skipping outputs with anonymous function in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096281/skipping-outputs-with-anonymous-function-in-matlab)

[How to elegantly ignore some return values of a MATLAB function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747296/how-to-elegantly-ignore-some-return-values-of-a-matlab-function)

The reason why the ~ operator was added to MATLAB some versions ago was to prevent you from saving variables you do not need. If there would be a syntax like the one you are searching for, this would not have been necessary.

Comment: Thank you. It seems you are correct. The [~,ans]=max(x) is unfortunately not supported as an expression though, making it necessary to define an extra function.