# sorting cell array in matlab and getting the new indices

Tags: matlab, cell

I have H which is n by n cell array , each cell contains a vector of numbers that I want to sort in ascending order , this is the code that I have tried

```
   HH = cellfun(@sort,H, 'UniformOutput', false)
```

the code worked perfectly but the problem that I want to have the indices of the element of vector,

for example: if a cell in this array contains [ 7 5 6 8] , it will be sorted as [ 5 6 7 8 ] & the indices are [2 3 1 4].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Gnovice ([Skipping outputs with anonymous function in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096281/skipping-outputs-with-anonymous-function-in-matlab)) you can just specify `cellfun` with two outputs!

```
[HH, HH_ind] = cellfun(@sort,H, 'UniformOutput', false)
```